# Constructor parameter names and class member names

Tags: scala

I generally understand how Scala deals with constructor parameters, i.e.
generating getter for val and getter/setter for var.
I also have found quite a few discussions about name clashes between
constructor parameters and class members.

For those names w/o val & var, I expect that if they're prefixed with `this.`, then class members instead should
be used. But that's not the case.

```
class A(val a: Int) {
  def m = println("A.a: " + a)
}

class B(a: Int) extends A(2 * a) {
  override def m = {
    super.m
    println("@a: " + a)
    println("this.a: " + this.a)  // this is @a, not A.a
  }
}

object TestApp extends App {
    val b = new B(10)
    b.m
    println(b.a); // this is A.a
}
```

Output:

```
A.a: 20
@a: 10
this.a: 10
20
```

I feel that it's slightly weird but is there a design reason behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote in your question Scala generates a getter for a `val`, so when you declare a `val` parameter in you `A` class, it actually has a method `m` and a field `a`, which are inherited by the `B` class. But you also have an `a` parameter in you `B` class, which is doubled and passed as an argument to the super constructor of `A`. To understand what's going on, turn on option `-Xprint:typer` for your repo and paste your code, e.g `A` represented like this:

```
class A extends scala.AnyRef {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val a: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def a: Int = A.this.a;
  def <init>(a: Int): A = {
    A.super.<init>();
    ()
  };
  def m: Unit = scala.this.Predef.println("A.a: ".+(A.this.a))
}
```

As you can see Scala created a hidden `private[this]` field for you `a` parameter. And here is representation for the `B` class:

```
class B extends A {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val a: Int = _;
  def <init>(a: Int): B = {
    B.super.<init>(2.*(a));
    ()
  };
  override def m: Unit = {
    B.super.m;
    println("@a: ".+(B.this.a));
    println("this.a: ".+(this.a))
  }
}
```

As you can see Scala also defined `private[this]` field for your `a` parameter in the `B` class. But because you didn't mark it as a `val` value, it didn't generate new `a` getter, which is still defined as `A.this.a`, but not `B.this.a`, so that's why you r getting `20` when calling `b.a`.

As an answer, i don't think that there is some complex design behind this, it looks logical and quite reasonable. If you rename your `a` param in `B` class constructor and pass it to `A`, nothing would change.